# Arduino serial communication failing after first run

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio, serial-port, arduino

I am currently creating a visual basic program to control my Arduino through serial communication, the problem is that after i send my first string from VB to the arduino, `if (Serial.available() )` no longer works the next time i send a string...

This is an example of the string im sending to the Arduino from VB:
`5,10,0,0,0050,0100,00,1,0,0050,0100,01,2,0,0050,0100,02`

Here is the Arduino Code:

```
int functions[3][5];
int fLength, numF = 0;
int minF, minFIdx = 98;
String functionString = "";
uint8_t dataPin  = 2;    // Yellow wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin = 3;    // Green wire on Adafruit Pixels
Adafruit_WS2801 strip = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)11, (uint16_t)9, dataPin, clockPin);


void setup()
{
  //Start Comm on BAUD 9600
 Serial.begin(9600); 
 delay(2);
 strip.begin();
 strip.show();
}
void loop()
{

  //If serial communication exists, build string
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.print("Serial On");
      delay(5);
    while (Serial.available())
    {
      functionString.concat(Serial.read());
    }
    //sort all data into arrays
    int fSet = 2;
    int numStrings = 0;
    for (int z = 0; getValue(functionString, ',', z); z++)
    {
      numStrings++;
    }

    fLength = stringToNumber(getValue(functionString, ',', 0));
    numF = stringToNumber(getValue(functionString, ',', 1));
    for (int j = 0; j < numF; j++)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < fLength; i ++)
      {
         functions[j][i] = stringToNumber(getValue(functionString, ',', fSet));
         if (fSet < numStrings -1)
         {
            fSet++; 
         }
      } 
    }
    functionString = "";
  }
  //sort and find the minimum priority w/ index of function if min is 98
  if (minF >= 98)
  {
    for (int u = 0; u < numF; u++)
    {
      if (functions[u][4] < minF)
      {
         minF = functions[u][7]; 
         minFIdx = u;
      }
    }
  }
  //select case for the function index pulled prior
  switch (minFIdx)
  {
   case 0:
   Serial.print("Case 0");
    break;
   case 1:
   Serial.print("Case 1");
    break;
   case 2:
   Serial.print("Case 2");
    break; 
  }
}
```

if you take a look at the `Serial.print("Serial On");`  line, it only returns "Serial On" the first time i send the string therefore im assuming that its only making it into the `if (Serial.available())` once.  The only way to get it to return the "Serial On" again is to re-upload the code to the arduino, nothing needs to be done on the VB side so i think the problem is somewhere in the arduino code, below is a snap shot of the VB program, on "Send" it should return "Serial On"

~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Just had a thought, is there anyway that my own debug command in interrupting my serial communication? the `Serial.print("Serial On");` does anyone know if this is possible???

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT 2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Well i was able to discover the issue, the only problem is it makes no sense, for some reason the piece of code specified below stops ALL serial communication, to and from the arduino..... can anyone tell me why this is and how i could go about fixing it?

```
for (int z = 0; getValue(functionString, ',', z); z++)
    {
      numStrings++;
    }
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT 3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Here is the getValue() code you guys were looking for

```
String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
{
  int found = 0;
  int strIndex[] = {0, -1};
  int maxIndex = data.length()-1;

  for(int i=0; i<=maxIndex && found<=index; i++){
    if(data.charAt(i)==separator || i==maxIndex){
        found++;
        strIndex[0] = strIndex[1]+1;
        strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
    }
  }

  return found>index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}
```

[image: Visual Basic GUI]

Comment: Just guessing, does the getValue() function require a zero terminated string?

Comment: Can we see the code for getValue()?

Comment: @Jeff and Adam, just added!

Comment: @Hockeyman271  Just FYI.  There is now a specialized Arduino stack: http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're reading char by char, concatenating them into string, and finally parsing the string into an integer. Have a look at the Arduino function https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt it does all of this : simply reads an integer number from the serial port. It will stop at the comma so you've got to call it several times to read all your parameters.